# Why is Vim for Debian compiled without clipboard?

Tags: linux, installing

I'm curious as to why the default Debian package for vim (the one you normally get by `sudo apt-get install vim`) isn't compiled with clipboard support?

Neither the regular `-clipboard` or `-Xterm-clipboard` is enabled, **why**?

There might be reason to not include -Xterm-clipboard on Debian installations without X-server installed, but the regular `-clipboard`?

Any insight into why this is would be helpfull.

(*Clarification: I know I can compile Vim with these flags, I just want to know why they aren't enabled by default.*)

Comment: What provides the clipboard if not X? xterm-clipboard is a different thing; that is for the buffers that xterm provides (see, for example, https://askubuntu.com/a/541730/158442).

Comment: but xterm-clipboard is also a feature provided by the X server

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I'm not saying it isn't, I'm talking about OP's misconception, probably from `xterm-clipboard`'s name, that it is a X feature and **the other isn't**, when both are. `xterm-clipboard`'s name, of course comes from it being for xterm-like buffers, not because it's for X.

Comment: @muru there exists no such thing as an xterm-like buffer. What you mean are X cut buffers, which is a feature of the X Server providing some means of inter-process communication between X clients, one usually being called Clipboard (Ctrl-V, CTRL-X, Ctrl-V in the usual desktop clients) and the other being middle mouse pasting of whatever was selected with the mouse previously. Although this is called xterm_clipboard it has nothing to do with xterm.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt huh, I always thought this cut buffer was something from xterm, like screen's paste buffer, and this feature supported such buffers. Thanks for correcting!

Comment: The smartass in me would tell you to install Neovim since it dispenses with pretty much all the compile flags in favour of just trying things at runtime. For example, the clipboard uses xsel/xclip instead of linking against a bunch of X libraries.

Comment: In order to use the stripped down version (without the full gtk dependencies) on a server, but still have X11 and clipboard support, you could use the `vim-athena` package (on Debian/Ubuntu at least)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [package description contains](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/vim)

> This package contains a version of vim compiled with a rather 
>   standard set of features.  This package does not provide a GUI 
>   version of Vim.  See the other vim-* packages if you need more  (or
>   less).

I believe this was made, because using the clipboard would involve linking against X libraries, which means, you couldn't install vim without also installing a bunch of X dependencies which you usually do not want in a server (or minimal) environment.

This means, if you want the clipboard feature, you should install e.g. the package `vim-gtk` (which despite its name also contains a non-gui vim).

For a similar reason, the package `vim-nox` exists. It does not depend on the X server, but needs additional libraries like liblua, libperl, libpython and does therefore install those additional dependencies (which you also probably do not need in a server environment), but no X libraries (like GTK or X11 ones needed for the gui and the clipboard).

Comment: Ahh I thought you *could* copy-paste on a non GUI install of Linux. That's why I thought the flag `-clipboard` was for Vim to acess the system copy-paste register.

(You can using X-Copy but I meant by deafult)

Comment: @GustavBlomqvist: You can, by using the regular command line clipboards, ie, select text, middle click to paste, and using GPM bindings.

Answer (score 8):

VIM is intended to be a portable editor that "just works" on all systems. By having the default version use the clipboard functionality, it will need to link against X11 libraries, and a separate version of VIM would need to be compiled for desktop versus server (no pre-installed X11/xorg) builds. This is why the `vim` and `vim-gtk` packages are provided.

If you want to compile the command-line version of VIM (I use it with Guake/yakuake all the time), here's the build/install script for Debian-based systems.

```
# Get the compile-dependencies of vim
sudo apt-get -y build-dep vim
# Install the "checkinstall" tool so the "make install" step is
# wrapped and the result is a .deb file that can be removed later by
# your package manager rather than having to hunt down every file deployed
# by "make install", which might not be possible if it overwrites existing
# system files.
sudo apt-get -y install checkinstall
# Install python dev
sudo apt-get -y install python-dev
# Install xorg dev
sudo apt-get -y install xorg-dev
# Install git
sudo apt-get -y install git
# Get the source
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git vim_source
# Remove ./configure cache in case we have to run this twice due to permissions
# related issues.
rm vim_source/src/auto/config.cache
# Compile it
cd vim_source
make clean
./configure \
    --enable-perlinterp=dynamic \
    --enable-pythoninterp=dynamic \
    --enable-rubyinterp=dynamic \
    --enable-cscope \
    --enable-gui=auto \
    --enable-gtk2-check \
    --enable-gnome-check \
    --with-features=normal \
    --with-x \
    --with-compiledby="DevNull <darkstar@/dev/null>" \
    --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config-$(uname -m)-linux-gnu
# Build quickly (8 parallel jobs, hope your system doesn't get overwhelmed)
make -j8
# Need root to install
sudo checkinstall
```

Comment: What in this recipe actually introduces the clipboard behavior? enable-gui? --with-x?